# Clearing a log file owned by root

Tags: log-files

I need to clear a log file with:

```
cat /dev/null > error.log
```

The problem is that the file is owned by root

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15505 Feb  9 15:08 error.log
```

and this doesn't work

```
$ sudo cat /dev/null > error.log 
-bash: error.log: Permission denied
```

no idea why... so how could I get around this?

Comment: Just wanted to share a shortcut.. `> error.log` will zero the file just the same. (Use the answer below to combine it with sudo.)

Comment: [man truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo sh -c "cat /dev/null > error.log"
```

The problem is that with the command you used, you are really running two commands: the first cat is run as root (via sudo) but everything else is run as your user. The above method resolves that.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on) answer over on U&L has more information on this.